# Fixing GHCi 7.2.1 on Mavericks

Tags: haskell, gcc

Because of Apples using clang compiler with Xcode 5 instead of a gcc compiler the current Haskell shell doesn't work. There have been two work arounds suggested.

(1) Installing a gcc compiler with brew and changing the settings to reflect this refer to that compiler location

/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.6.3-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-7.6.3/settings

(2) To make use of clang-xcode5-wrapper script  by placing in somewhere like /usr/local/bin and referring to that location in the settings file

These fixes seem to date back about three months. I've tried both and that don't work!

Is there any known fix for the current version of Haskell on Mavericks?

Comment: The "current" version of GHC is 7.6.3, not 7.2.1.

Comment: Could you please paste the full error you get when trying to run ghci or ghc?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that installing gcc4.2 with MacPorts (and `port select`ing it) solved the problem. Although I have no idea if it would work for you, since you haven't provided any indication of what "don't work" means.

Comment: When I attempt to enter the Haskell shell the following occurs: > ghci /usr/local/bin/ghc-7.2.1: line 9: /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.2.1/ghc: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/ghc-7.2.1: line 9: exec: /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.2.1/ghc: cannot execute: No such file or directory
Donfox1-iMac:invoicedb donfox1$

Comment: I attempted the same thing with brew. I installed gcc4.2 and modified the settings file at /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/Current/usr/lib/ghc-7.6.3. I modified this to reflect the location of the gcc4.2 compiler.  This resulted in no change when invoking the GHCi shell!

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to this problem is to use Homebrew for now rather than downloaing and installing from haskell.org.

Just **brew install haskell-platform** does the trick of getting GHC 7.6.3 and this includes the getting required the gcc compiler.